# Unable to compile the example for Eigen SVD

Tags: c++, eigen3

I am trying to compile the example provided for [Eigen::JacobiSVD](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1JacobiSVD.html) and I am getting the following error,

```
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h: In instantiation of ‘Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>& Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>::compute(const MatrixType&, unsigned int) [with _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>; int QRPreconditioner = 40; Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>::MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>]’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h:549:14:   required from ‘Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>::JacobiSVD(const MatrixType&, unsigned int) [with _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>; int QRPreconditioner = 40; Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>::MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>]’
demo.cpp:9:55:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h:692:27: error: ‘struct Eigen::internal::qr_preconditioner_impl<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, 40, 0, true>’ has no member named ‘run’
     m_qr_precond_morecols.run(*this, m_scaledMatrix);
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h:693:27: error: ‘struct Eigen::internal::qr_preconditioner_impl<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, 40, 1, true>’ has no member named ‘run’
     m_qr_precond_morerows.run(*this, m_scaledMatrix);
```

Could you please help me with this? Thanks

Code :

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/SVD>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main () {
    MatrixXf m = MatrixXf::Random(3,2);
    cout << "Here is the matrix m:" << endl << m << endl;
    JacobiSVD<MatrixXf, ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV> svd(m);
    cout << "Its singular values are:" << endl << svd.singularValues() << endl;
    cout << "Its left singular vectors are the columns of the thin U matrix:" << endl << svd.matrixU() << endl;
    cout << "Its right singular vectors are the columns of the thin V matrix:" << endl << svd.matrixV() << endl;
    Vector3f rhs(1, 0, 0);
    cout << "Now consider this rhs vector:" << endl << rhs << endl;
    cout << "A least-squares solution of m*x = rhs is:" << endl << svd.solve(rhs) << endl;
}
```

**g++ : 7.5**

**Eigen : 3.4.0**

Comment: I can reproduce this issue with gcc-11. Looks a lot like a bug. Weird that it is such an obvious issue. I think you should report it on https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This looks very much like a bug. I looked at the code and there is no way it can work. I'll file a bug report.

As a workaround, this should work even though it is marked as deprecated:

```
JacobiSVD<MatrixXf> svd;
svd.compute(m, ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV);
```

The underlying issue is that during template-specialization, the code does not separate the Compute options from the QR preconditioner options. So it doesn't find a suitable implementation.

### EDIT

The issue is with a disparity between the online documentation and the current release. The documentation is for 3.4.90 but the last released version is 3.4.0.

In 3.4.90 the compute parameters must be declared in *either* the template *or* the runtime parameters, but not both.

In 3.4.0 and earlier, the compute options must be declared in the runtime parameters.

```
// works in all versions but deprecation warning in 3.4.90
Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXf> svd;
svd.compute(m, Eigen::ComputeThinV | Eigen::ComputeThinU);
// or
Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXf> svd(m, Eigen::ComputeThinV | Eigen::ComputeThinU);

// works in 3.4.90
Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXf, Eigen::ComputeThinV | Eigen::ComputeThinU> svd;
svd.compute(m);
```